# delete the colmuns which are contained just NA or 0 or both values

Tags: r

What should I do if I want to remove the columns which are contained just the 0 or NA or both values?

```
mat <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
c("A05363", "A05370", "A05380", "A05397", "A05400", "A05426"), c("X1.110590170", "X1.110888172", "X1.110906406", "X1.110993854", "X1.110996710", "X1.111144756")))
```

My output should be like this:

```
        X1.110590170   X1.110906406   X1.110993854   X1.111144756
A05363             0              0              0              0
A05370             0              0              0             NA
A05380             1              2              0              0
A05397             0              0              1              2
A05400             2              0              0              0
A05426             0             NA              0              0
```

Comment: I did actually update my answer on your previous question in response to your comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397042/remove-the-columns-with-the-colsums-0/31397062?noredirect=1#comment50812762_31397062

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Seems to me you _should_ have the power to close R questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the columns using the apply function along the columns.

You will simply have to use the `all` function to make sure that `all` values in the column satisfy the logic: `is.na(x) | x == 0`.

```
filter_cols <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) !all(is.na(x) | x == 0))
mat[,filter_cols]
#'         X1.110590170 X1.110906406 X1.110993854 X1.111144756
#'  A05363            0            0            0            0
#'  A05370            0            0            0           NA
#'  A05380            1            2            0            0
#'  A05397            0            0            1            2
#'  A05400            2            0            0            0
#'  A05426            0           NA            0            0
```