# Remove columns with NA's and/or Zeros Only

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, na

I have a sample dataset which looks something similar to the one below:

```
d= data.frame(a = c(1,5,56,4,9), 
              b = c(0,0,NA,0,NA), 
              c = c(98,67,NA,3,7), 
              d = c(0,0,0,0,0), 
              e = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

which would be:

```
| a  |  b |  c | d | e  |
|----|:--:|---:|---|----|
| 1  |  0 | 98 | 0 | NA |
| 5  |  0 | 67 | 0 | NA |
| 56 | NA | NA | 0 | NA |
| 4  | 0  | 3  | 0 | NA |
| 9  | NA | 7  | 0 | NA |
```

I need to remove all such columns which have:

```
1. NA's and Zeros
2. Only Zeros
3. Only NA's
```

So based on the above dataset, columns b,d and e should be eliminated. So, I first need to find out which columns have such conditions and then delete them.

I went through this link [Remove the columns with the colsums=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397042/remove-the-columns-with-the-colsums-0) but I'm not clear with the solution. Also, it doesn't provide me the desired output.

The final output would be:

```
| a  |  c |
|----|:--:|
| 1  | 98 |
| 5  | 67 |
| 56 | NA |
| 4  | 3  |
| 9  | 7  |
```

Comment: @akrun I'm sorry. I made the edit. They are numeric.

Comment: Thank you.  I tested your data and it seems to  be working fine for  me  to return the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to create a logical vector with `colSums` based on the number of `NA` or 0 elements in each column

```
d[!colSums(is.na(d)|d ==0) == nrow(d)]
#  a    c
#1  1   98
#2  5   67
#3 56   NA
#4  4    3
#5  9    7
```

Or another option is to `replace` all the 0s to `NA` and then apply `is.na`

```
d[colSums(!is.na(replace(d, d == 0, NA))) > 0]
```

Or more compactly with `na_if`

```
d[colSums(!is.na(na_if(d, 0))) > 0]
```

Comment: Well, I have tried this on my real dataset. I don't know why, but it does not remove the columns which have both NA's and zeros. Even in the above sample dataset, it does not delete the column e. The other approach I could think of was to replace all the NA's with zeros and then remove the columns with all zeros, but that too doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @hk2  I get the expected output based on your example.  May be you used the earlier version

Answer (score 2):

In `base` and assuming that we have different type of columns:

```r
as.data.frame(Filter(function(x) !all(x=="NA" | x == "0"), {lapply(d, as.character)}))
```

Using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  select(which(colSums(abs(.), na.rm = T) != 0))
```

---

***Output:***

```r
#>    a  c
#> 1  1 98
#> 2  5 67
#> 3 56 NA
#> 4  4  3
#> 5  9  7
```

Comment: This would be true if all the columns are numeric. However, if some of those columns are of different data types such as character and date, how will the above code be modified?

Comment: @hk2 please edit your dataset and make it representative of your actual dataset https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` column-wise and remove columns which has `all`, `NA` or 0's.

```
d[!apply(d == 0 | is.na(d), 2, all)]

#   a  c
#1  1 98
#2  5 67
#3 56 NA
#4  4  3
#5  9  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Very strange to store NAs and 0 as strings, but there you go...

```
bad_column <- function(z) {
  all(z %in% c("NA", "0"))
}

d[, !sapply(d, bad_column), drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: The post has been edited. I have changed them to be numeric.