# Removing columns from a matrix using a list of column names

Tags: r

I'm attempting to remove all `colSums !=0` columns from my matrix. Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397042/remove-the-columns-with-the-colsums-0) I have gotten close.

```
data2<-subset(data, Gear == 20) #subset off larger data matrix
 i <- (colSums(data2[,3:277], na.rm=T) != 0) #column selection in this line limits to numeric columns only 
 data3<- data2[, i]  #select only columns with non-zero colSums
```

This creates a vector, i, that properly identifies the columns to be removed using a logical True/False. However, the final line is removing columns by some logic other than my intentional *if true then include if false then exclude*. 
**The goal**: remove all columns in that range that have a `colSums == 0` . 
**The problem**: my current code does not seem to properly identify said columns
Suggestion as to what I'm missing?

Update: 
Adding dummy data to use:

```
a<-matrix(1:10, ncol = 10,nrow=10)
a
a[,c(3,5,8)]<-0
a
i <- (colSums(a, na.rm=T) != 0) 
 b<- a[, i]
```

it works well here, so I'm not sure why it won't work above on real data.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: The only real problem I see is changing variable names. You check for column sums in `data2` but then you are subsetting `n20` in the final line. Those are probably completely different data.frames

Comment: You can use `n20[, c(1:2, which(i) + 2)]`

Comment: @MrFlick you are correct on the data frame referencing. That was an editorial mistake bringing it to the question from R. I also just went to make a reproducible example with dummy data and this line works perfectly fine on the dummy data... grrr. Also: I updated the original post as per your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the column names from the `colSums` and concatenate with the first two column names, which was not used for creating the condition with `colSums` to select the columns of interest

```
data[c(names(data)[1:2], names(which(i1)))]
```

Comment: The original post generates the names vector well. It's just not sub-setting the new matrix by that list.

Comment: @Jesse001 the original post generates a logical vector.  Here, it is subsetting that logical vector to get only the column names where there is TRUE values

Comment: @Jesse001 you can check `v1 <- setNames(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 1:4)#
names(which(v1))`

Comment: that seems to have done the trick, thanks. Sorry I misunderstood the answer originally.